# How to avoid the rebase command in clearTool popups a screen?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I am trying to rebase a baseline using this command in ClearTool:

```
rebase -bas [baseline_code]
```

However, after this command, a screen pop up with this question:

> Do you wish to name the Deliver/Rebase activity (if no, press Enter or Cancel to use the default name)

I want to avoid this screen because I want to implement it in a code, for this reason, is there any command to add in this rebase, then it can stop to show this screen? Or is there any kind of set up that I have to do in ClearCase to stop to show it?

My ClearCase version is 9.0.1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to disable some trigger that I found as suggested.
However, I was not allowed because I am not part of the ClearCase group or object owner.
For this reason, a college of my work gave this tip to create a read-only child streams, that avoid to show the message (screen). And it worked.

**mkstream -in "stream parent" -readonly "stream name"**

After that, I could do:

**rebase -bas "baseline"**

**rebase -complete**

Answer (score 0):

Since the message "Do you wish to name the Deliver/Rebase activity" does not seem to be a standard/native one, it is possible it comes from a trigger.

From there, see "[How to disable a trigger in a VOB or determine if an existing trigger is already disabled](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21368084)"

Check its list with [`cleartool lstype`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lstype.htm):

```
cd/path/to/my/view/myVob
cleartool lstype -invob \aVob -kind trtype
```