# How do I create a new clearcase element inside an unreserved checked out directory?

Tags: clearcase, checkout

## Background

In ClearCase, you can make unreserved [checkouts](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_checkout.htm) if a certain file is already checked out by another view with the following command:

```
ct co -unreserved <element>
```

You can also add a new element to clearcase with the following command

```
ct mkelem <new_element>
```

However, using the [mkelem](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkelem.htm) command on a file requires that the directory of the file be a checked-out clearcase element.

## Issue

I am trying to create a new clearcase element in a directory.  This directory is current checked out by another view, thus I need to make an unreserved checkout.  The unreserved checkout works perfectly.  However, when I try to run `ct mkelem newFile` after making an unreserved checkout of the directory, I get this error:

> % ct mkelem newFile
>
> Creation comments for "newFile": . Created
>   element "newFile" (type "text_file").
>
> ERROR: User [user_name]
>   cannot make reserved checkouts for this file type or branch in this area. File
>   is [/vobs/directory/to/newFile@@/main/0]  You can still
>   make an unreserved checkout if needed.

Which lead me to wonder...

## Question

Is there a way to make a new clearcase element inside an unreserved checkout of a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a custom error message: "You can still make an unreserved checkout".
Meaning it is not natively displayed by ClearCase.

So check if there are any VOB trigger in place which would enforce such a policy (no unreserved checkout of a directory): use `cleartool lstype -invob \aVob -kind trtype`, as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50537590/6309).

Because you *can* checkout a folder concurrently in a reserved and unreserved way... which can lead to [evil twins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27635705/6309), as this thread illustrates:

> evil twins were introduced from users in parallel directory versions, either from another branch or different versions in the same branch (a user had an old unreserved checkout, added a file that another user already added in a reserved checkout later in the version tree, thus you now have evil twins.)